# matplotlib - scatter and plot look weird

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on machine learning and I'm using jupyter notebook. Here is the code for drawing a diagram with matplotlib with the xtest, ytest and y_pred data.

```
    %matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.scatter(xtest, ytest,  color='black')
    plt.plot(xtest, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=1)
    plt.xlabel("Value")
    plt.ylabel("Overall")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

But when i try the code my diagram look like this instead

[image]

What am i missing because they don't look the same.

Comment: Any link for the tutorial?

Comment: plt.plot(xtest, y_pred, color='blue', linestyle='none', marker='^')

Comment: here is the link for the tutorial @GVelascoh https://www.uruit.com/blog/2018/02/16/soccer-and-machine-learning-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

- Your data are strings. But you need to use numbers to correctly plot the data.
- Your data is not sorted. You need to sort it not to have zig-zag lines appear in the plot.